# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework database exist after deleting mdf-File

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core site just works fine. But when I delete the database file inside my user folder, it always tells me after restarting and creating the site, the database already exists. 
As workaround it helps changing the database name.

But what do I have to delete to get rid of the database?

Comment: Have you tried to drop the database from the management studio?

Comment: It's not available there. I can find system databases only.

Comment: If you are using code first, have you tried to delete migration folder from the project?

Comment: Yes, no difference.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the database through EF command? `dotnet ef database drop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using SQL LocalDB. When you delete the mdf file you also need to delete the local instance of localDB.

In package manager (or Visual Studio Debug Commandline) enter (`PM>` is the Package manager prompt, don't enter this of course ;)).

```
PM> SqlLocalDb.exe info
MSSQLLocalDB
v11.0
```

Now you know you have two local DBs, `MSSQLLocalDB` and `v11.0`.

First stop it

```
PM> SqlLocalDb.exe stop MSSQLLocalDB
```

Then delete it

```
PM> SqlLocalDb.exe delete MSSQLLocalDB
```

Finally start it again

```
PM> SqlLocalDb.exe delete MSSQLLocalDB
```

Or created it before if necessary

```
PM> SqlLocalDb.exe create MSSQLLocalDB
```